# Why my pluck function not working?

Tags: javascript, callback

I thought my map and pluck functions are collection correct, but when I try to call pluck to get "type" of car object, it returns an empty array....? empty array...???

update: thanks for pointing out that it is object.....So I added for in in my map function, but seems not working? is anything wrong?

```
    function map(collection,iterator){
        var result=[];
       if(Array.isArray(collection)){
        for (var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
            result.push(iterator(collection[i]));
            }
        }else{
        for (var key in collection){
            result.push(iterator(collection[key]))};
            }
            return result;
        };

    function pluck(collection, key) {
        return map(collection, function (value) {
            return value[key]
        });
    }

    var car = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" };

    console.log(pluck(car, function (auto) {
        return auto.type;
    }));

> the result: []
```

Comment: Syntax of if-statement is not correct.

Comment: can you please tell me which part is not correct?

Comment: This one-> if(Array.isArray(collection){

Comment: You are'nt closing brackets of "if" properly.

Comment: thanks, I got it, but now the result return :[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]

Comment: If you will keep editing the question itself, it will not help when others will have similar doubts in future.

Comment: I will keep the original question,  but now the result return :[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]  ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97237/discussion-between-danny-and-rajat).

Comment: Danny are you still in Chat? We need to know what result you would expect as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function map(collection, filter) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
    result.push(filter(collection[i]))
  }
  return result;
}

function pluck(collection, filter) {
  return map(collection, filter);
}

var cars = [{type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white"}]

var result = pluck(cars, function(auto) {
  return auto.type;
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(pluck(car, function (auto) {
    return auto.type;
}));
```

should be

```
console.log(pluck(car, 'type'));
```

Also, `car` needs to be an array.

```
var car = [{ type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" }];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing this

> var car = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" };

While your map function expects array.

Use **for-in** loop if you want to pass object.

Comment: This part  >  if(Array.isArray(collection){

Answer (score 2):

Pluck function only makes sense for arrays, because only arrays make sense to map. For objects you want to just read property:

```
var car = { type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" };

console.log( car.type );
```

Comment: thanks, what if there's a few objects in an array? in this case how should I write the pluck function?

Answer (score 1):

because its an object, not array